# Half-installed ttf-mscorefonts-installer

Tags: apt, fonts

13.04 raring ringtail  - 64 bit

How do I repair or remove the package so that I can install netflix on my laptop?

I get this error message from `apt-get`:

```
dpkg: error processing ttf-mscorefonts-installer (--configure):
 package ttf-mscorefonts-installer is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status `half-installed')
```

Comment: now try `sudo apt-get install -f`

Answer (score 1):

to completely remove a package

```
sudo apt-get purge package
sudo apt-get clean
```

you can then try to reinstall.

If it still fails my suggestion would be to copy the MS fonts in an USB drive from a Windows box and manually copy them into `/home/matteo/.local/share/fonts`.

Open Nautilus (Files) then press `CTRL+L` and paste `/home/matteo/.local/share` (and press enter) in the location bar. If you don't have the `fonts` folder create it and copy the fonts inside of it.