# How can I follow the instructions from "Half-installed ttf-mscorefonts-installer"?

Tags: 64-bit, 14.10

Can you show me how can I follow this instruction from [Half-installed ttf-mscorefonts-installer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325626/half-installed-ttf-mscorefonts-installer)?

> My suggestion would be to copy the MS fonts in an USB drive from a Windows box and manually copy them into `/home/matteo/.local/share/fonts`.Open Nautilus (Files) then press CTRL+L and paste `/home/matteo/.local/share` (and press Enter) in the location bar. If you don't have the fonts folder, create it and copy the fonts inside of it.

I am new to Ubuntu and don't know exactly how to follow this. Can you give me the links explained about it? This suggestion is to solve `dpkg: error processing ttf-mscorefonts-installer (--configure): package ttf-mscorefonts-installer is not ready for configuration cannot configure (current status 'half-installed')` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer addresses the ttf-mscorefonts-installer 'half-installed' error. This error can occur because Microsoft True Type Core Fonts for the web, which is installed by the ttf-mscorefonts-installer, is Microsoft proprietary software,  and although it can be installed free of charge, it cannot be installed without accepting the Microsoft End User License Agreement (EULA). The problem is that the Microsoft EULA window pops up behind the Ubuntu Software Center window, and since it is smaller than the Ubuntu Software Center window, it is often completely covered up so that it can't be seen. Then when you close the Ubuntu Software Center window, it also closes the EULA window, resulting in the ttf-mscorefonts-installer package being 'half-installed'.

If this happened to you, then you have to uninstall the ttf-mscorefonts-installer package and reinstall it, preferably from the terminal, so that the EULA window won't have any big windows to hide behind.

Run `sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer` and accept the EULA, or else if you already have ttf-mscorefonts-installer installed and you didn't accept the EULA, then uninstall ttf-mscorefonts-installer and reinstall it like this:

```
sudo dpkg -P ttf-mscorefonts-installer  
sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> keys to accept the EULA in the Microsoft TrueType core fonts window that pops up. The terminal will output a new message each time it finishes downloading a new font. Wait a bit until the terminal tells you that it's finished downloading and installing the Microsoft TrueType core fonts.

---

If this method doesn't work, then  download [the latest version of ttf-mscorefonts-installer](http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/contrib/m/msttcorefonts/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb) and double-click it to install it using the Ubuntu Software Center.